Facebook Open Graph Debugger says "og:image could not be processed" but it's known to be working
Facebook Sharing Debugger return error "Provided og:image URL, image_link could not be processed as an image. It may be corrupted or may have an invalid format." but image known to be working in other medias
So we started to have this problem for last couple of weeks. When we trying to share website link (for example, https://ain.ua/2024/10/16/v-ukrayini-persa-privatna-skola-operatoriv-droniv-otrimala-sertifikat/?fbclid=IwZXh0bgNhZW0CMTEAAR30W8i60QKSLoIZ45bR2kf6NxL28Wtp5XbGwH_7_cwMwXFcv4_Oj0xzxUI_aem_tnj8fNnx1Z-wobzRhSg4Cw) in FB sometimes there is no thumbnail and inside sharing debugger says that image may be corrupted. In other social media/messangers sharing works very well. Adding more og tags didn't help much.
We store images in AWS. Website uses Laravel. If you faced this issue and know way to solve it I would be very thankful to you. I'm tired from solving it.

It turns out there was problem with robots.txt for AWS.
I added
User-agent: facebookexternalhit
Disallow:
User-agent: facebookcatalog
Disallow:
User-agent: meta-externalagent
Disallow:
User-agent: meta-externalfetcher
Disallow:
And now it works
